# The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration , even though file is available in defined path

Tags: apache, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, adsapi-php.ini

I have followed all the steps mention in https://www.wikihow.com/Install-phpMyAdmin-on-Your-Windows-PC and checked file paths and those are correct.

Even after that I am getting an error **"The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration"**

I have verified my extensions are uncommented and correct paths has been giving.

Here is the lines which I have added in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
   PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/php/"
```

And here is my php.ini file.

```
 extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_curl.dll
 extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_gd2.dll
   extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_intl.dll
   extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_mbstring.dll
   extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_mysqli.dll
   extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_openssl.dll
   extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_soap.dll
   extension=C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext/php_xmlrpc.dll
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini file set the `extension_dir` to  `C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext` then change the extension values to simply the name of the extension.

```
extension_dir = "C:/Program Files (x86)/php/ext"

extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

Comment: Not working. I am getting this error only when I am using apache servers , but when I am using Wamp it is working fine

Comment: The WAMP package includes Apache so your response doesn't make a lot of sense. Do you have multiple versions of Apache and/or PHP installed?

Comment: Point noted but not aware why it works with WAMP and not with apache stand alone server. Again tried with Apache server and still getting same error.